# How do I count all placemarks visible in the plugin at a given time?

Tags: timestamp, kml, google-earth, timespan, google-earth-plugin

I have created a time-aware animation involving thousands of placemarks representing population estimates at http://www.catalinagis.org/foxrecovery

I want to know how to count the sum of the total number of placemarks (in this case, points) that are visible at a given point in time. . .something like a time-based query.

The population estimate fluctuates year-to-year, so some points only last for a brief time span before they're extinguished; others persist from the beginning of the time span until the end.  There are over 3,000 points, so I don't want to go back through the KML one-by-one.

I was given yearly population estimates and then simulated die-off and repopulation on a monthly time scale to make the animation seem more "natural."  I created the KML some time ago and want to check myself to see if I did it correctly. . .and also display the count as the time slider is moved.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by visible? Do you mean just that it is loaded into the plugin, or visible in that it is currently being rendered on screen?

Comment: @Fraser I mean currently being rendered on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure 'rendered on screen' is what you mean - are you sure you don't want to count placemarks that would be rendered if they were in view (on by time but on the other side of the planet for example).

If you do mean rendered then issue with counting placemarks is that the only way to do it would be to compute the bounds of the current view, then test to see if a loaded placemark falls within the bounds and is visible.

This could take quite a long time if the KML dom is large as it requires the full DOM to be walked each tick of time then a check on each element in the DOM against the bounds view. You could possibly achieve something by executing the code as a batch function with the api.

If you want to try this then I would suggest you take a look at [earth-api-utility-library](https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/) it has useful methods for traversing the Kml dom and computing bounds objects - you should be able to use it to help you most of the way.

**EDIT:** If you don't mean rendered then that is much easier, it is still essentially the same iterative  process - but now you don't need to compute the view bounds or do any comparison against it.

To get the total visible placemarks at any point you simply need to walk the KML dom and check each placemarks visibility via `getVisiblity()` - something like so.

```
var gex = new GEarthExtensions(ge);

var function countVisiblePlacemarks() {
  var count = 0;
  gex.dom.walk({
    rootObject: ge,
    visitCallback: function() {
    if ('getType' in this &&
        this.getType() == 'KmlPlacemark' &&
        this.getVisibility())
        ++count;
    }
  });
  return count;
}
```

Obviously how you call `countVisiblePlacemarks` is up to you - on a timer, an api event, a button, etc). What you do with the resulting count is also up to you.

If you do use the extension library which I recommended and used in the example above [check the developers guide](https://developers.google.com/earth/articles/domtraversal) it is pretty useful.

Comment: I see the distinction now.  Yes, I want to know how many placemarks would be rendered if they were in view.  So, I suppose the answer to your initial question should be that I'm looking for how many placemarks are loaded into the plugin at a given time (assuming that if the time slider time is within a placemark's timespan then the placemark is considered "loaded" and otherwise not considered loaded).  I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Ah, I did think that but didn't want to presume. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  My goal is to update the count when the kml is initially loaded and whenever the time slider is moved.  I would display the count in a div (for the viewer, count translates to estimated fox population).  However, from my reading it seems that no API event is fired when the time slider is moved, making this a little more challenging (I think).

Comment: No worries, FYI you could probably get the same effect by simply calling the counting function on the `GEPlugin.frameend` event so that the count updates whenever the viewport has finished rendering. See: http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/event-frameend.html

Comment: You could also just use `setTimeout` to call the counting function every x seconds once the kml is loaded, but have the counting function exit immediately if ge.getTime().getHistoricalImageryEnabled() is false so that it only walks the DOM when the slider is present.

Comment: I implemented your solution using the frameend event.  Unfortunately, it's too resource intensive to be practical to walk the DOM this often with over 3,000 placemarks.  It seems like an instantaneous count of a large number of placemarks might be out of reach at this time.